# Invoke method on static filed using IL generator in C# reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, ilgenerator

I'm generating a new `Type` via `TypeBuilder` from C# reflection. The problem that I have right now is how to build method body to invoke method on static filed.

Right now my generated (at runtime) class looks like this:

```
public class Generated
{
    static private MyObject obj;

    public MyResponse Hello(MyRequest req1)
    {
        return obj.Hello(req1); // this part need to be grnerated
    }
}
```

So right now I'm generating method like this:

```
MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(
    methodInfo.Name,
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Final,
    CallingConventions.HasThis | CallingConventions.ExplicitThis,
    methodInfo.ReturnType,
    arguments);

ILGenerator il = mb.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull); // right now I'm just simply returning null
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

So please tell me how can I load static field on stack in Il generator and then invoke certain method on it.

Comment: First write that code in C# and look at what IL it generates with ildasm.exe.  Now it is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just used `ildasm.exe` to decompile class that I've posted in my question. If anyone would need do staff similar to mine, below you have Il code:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     class ConsoleApplication1.IMyInterface ConsoleApplication1.Controller::obj
IL_0006:  ldarg.1
IL_0007:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication1.MyResponse ConsoleApplication1.IMyInterface::Hello(class ConsoleApplication1.MyRequest)
IL_000c:  stloc.0
IL_000d:  br.s       IL_000f
IL_000f:  ldloc.0
IL_0010:  ret
```

Also in my code I've removed lines `IL_0000,c,d,f`, because (in my opinion) there are not needed.

Comment: Looking at the Release build version is better.

Comment: Which release build version? I don't understand you

Comment: You are looking at the Debug build of the assembly.  It has too many unnecessary IL instructions.  Switch to the Release configuration, then look again.

Comment: Ok, now I understand